# rest api that allows update to collection

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

what would be the best practice for allowing a WebAPI OData based webservice update an entire collection?

For example, we have an admin page that allows users to maintain a list of payment terms.  We have created a controller that is based on the PaymentTerm entity, which allows the standard Get, Get by key, Put, Post, and Delete, for working with single instances of the PaymentTerm Entity.  However, our UI team would like to retrieve a collection of payment terms (easily done with the standard Get collection), manipulate it locally, and then Put or Post the entire collection back to the server, rather than having to make a series of Put, Post, and Delete calls to the server.

I have tried creating an action method for this, and while I have managed to get it to work, it seems somewhat kludgy, as it requires an ID, as well as odata parameters (which contain the collection), and the ID is meaningless because at this point you are not working with an instance of a Payment Term, but an entire collection of them.

I could create a new controller solely for working with a collection of payment terms, but I'm not sure that would be much better, as it would end up having to have a base class declaration of

```
EntitySetController<PaymentTermCollection, int>
```

or the like, which would not make much sense as the collection would not have a key that had any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider support $batch ( Standard part of OData ) in your web api using EntitySetApiControllers
Then you can submit a bag of changes including post-put-delete of multiple entities to your sever easily, within support of JayData , breeze , ...
Good luck

Comment: looks to be the best way to handle it, thanks.  Unfortunately, $batch doesn't seem to be supported in the current release version of OData in WebAPI, so looks like I will have to find a workaround until the next update.

Comment: If you use EntitySetApiControllers instead of classic Api Controller class, then you can have $batch even in ASP.NET Web API

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation on this?  I have been unable to find anything about using $batch in a standard Web API (non OData) controller, and the only references I can find about using it in OData require the 5.0 version of OData to work, which is still pre-release.